# Which observables do Angular complete automatically?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Which observables **produced by Angular** are also completed by Angular?

For example:

- `HttpClient` completes any observables as the request finishes
- observables from the `Router` (parammap, queryparammap, etc) automatically complete when the route changes.

What other observables **from Angular** does Angular complete for you automatically and under what circumstances?

Comment: Tbh everything except http requests And local subjects, I would unsubscribe manually. I haven’t tested this in a while but back in v5/6 they still had bugs around route subscriptions completing which caused memory leaks.

Comment: @bryan60, thanks, I see there's still an open issue about it: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16261

Comment: Yea, it’s just a best practice IMO to always unsubscribe unless it’s a single shot type of observable like an http request or if it’s something strictly local to the component. Or preferably not subscribing at all and using async pipe whenever feasible. I could make arguments about even unsubscribing from http requests though if for instance you may change to a web socket or some caching subject mechanism in the future. I can’t think of anything else from angular that’s even supposed to safely complete for you though.

Answer (score 2):

> observables from the Router [...] automatically complete when the route changes.

I wouldn't say this is true. When the route changes, that view is **destroyed** and since each `ActivatedRoute` is associated with a route(thus with a route component), when the component is destroyed, everything inside it will be destroyed, as well any subscriptions to sources which belong to that component(e.g `ActivatedRoute.params`). At least this is what I've noticed, but it for sure does not emits a complete notification when a route changes.

The same would apply for `@ViewChildren`. Since it will query for elements from the current component's view, when the component will be destroyed, that source(`@ViewChildren.changes`) will be nulled out as well, so there is no need to manually unsubscribe.

Same for `valueChanges` or `statusChanges`(assuming that the form control is created in that component).

Memory leaks can occur when you have, for instance, a global service. Because it is **global** it just keeps references to subscribers, which can come from multiple places. But since the global service's existence does not depend on whether a component is destroyed, it's up to that component to let the service know that it is no longer interested in receiving values.

---

Some very interesting things happen with guards.

When using a `canLoad` guard, if you return an observable, you must make sure that your observable completes(e.g by adding `take(1)`). This is important as Angular **does not** automatically handle this for you:

```js
sbj = new BehaviorSubject(true)

canLoad (route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) {
  // Although it's returning `true`, it never completes
  return this.sbj;
}
```

From [its implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/apply_redirects.ts#L319-L349) we can see why:

```js
// Observable that will emit each `canLoad` individually
const obs = from(canLoad).pipe(map((injectionToken: any) => {
  const guard = moduleInjector.get(injectionToken);
  let guardVal;
  if (isCanLoad(guard)) {
    guardVal = guard.canLoad(route, segments);
  } /* ... */
  return wrapIntoObservable(guardVal);
}));

return obs.pipe(
  // `concatAll` === `mergeMap(obs => obs, 1)`
  // `concatAll` requires an observable to **complete** in order to subscribe to the next one
  concatAll(),
  /* ... */
  every(result => result === true),
);
```

On the other side, when using `canActivate` for example, it's another story. This time, Angular will automatically take the first value and then complete, so this should work:

```js
sbj = new BehaviorSubject(true);

canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

  return this.sbj;
}
```

As seen in the [implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/check_guards.ts#L113-L134):

```js
const canActivateObservables = canActivate.map((c: any) => {
  return defer(() => {
    const guard = getToken(c, futureARS, moduleInjector);
    let observable;

    if (isCanActivate(guard)) {
      observable = wrapIntoObservable(guard.canActivate(futureARS, futureRSS));
    } /* ... */

    // Only get the first emitted value and then complete
    return observable.pipe(first());
  });
});
return of(canActivateObservables).pipe(prioritizedGuardValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
>   pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
>   gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
>   potential memory leaks.

(from https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: I want to know which observable types that Angular *produces* will also be *completed* by Angular. This answer is only useful if I plan on using the observable in a template.